# "Communications Error - Check baud rate" after flashing NodeMCU with Latest .bin file

Tags: lua, esp8266, serial-communication, nodemcu

After flashing my ESP8266 NodeMCU from https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/releases/tag/1.5.4.1-master_20161201 latest firmware file, it constantly gives "Communications Error - Check baud rate" error over LuaLoader Software, while on Arduino Software gives "Unable to read" error.

Why is it so? Do help.

Comment: I don't know but the NodeMCU documentation explains that the baud rate setting in any tool should be 115200.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it erasing all the flash memory (4Mb in my case) before flashing. Here you'll find how to. http://www.pratikpanda.com/completely-format-erase-esp8266-flash-memory/

Another way to do a complete flash memory erase is with "esptool.py" and the "erase_flash" instruction. https://github.com/espressif/esptool